# MotionLayout: How to Limit the 'OnSwipe' event on a specific view instead of 'OnSwipe' on whole screen

Tags: android, android-animation, android-motionlayout

I have a motionlayout with the following 'layoutDescription' (scenes file)

```
    <Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:duration="1000">

    <OnSwipe
        motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/button"
        motion:touchAnchorSide="left"
        motion:dragDirection="dragLeft" />

</Transition>
<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <!--    ConstraintSet for starting -->
</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <!--    ConstraintSet for end -->
</ConstraintSet>
```

What I expect from here is if user drag the 'button' towards left side then it should perform the transition but what actually happening is when user drag left(swipe left) from any where in the screen this transition getting executed!

How to limit the animation work only when dragging the specified view?

(Im using "constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2" )

Comment: MotionLayout OnSwipe applies to whole screen. if you want achieve this task you can refer https://github.com/BALUSANGEM/UberSlideUp

Comment: Thank you @SurajGhadge. Your valuable comment leads me to find the solution!

Comment: Your welcome, it was great that its help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually for `onSwipe` you can use `touchRegionId` and `targetId` for `OnClick`

Comment: haha my bad! it's works. Its available from alpha 5 release. Thank you

Comment: I wonder if both `OnClick` and `OnSwipe` works for the same view for you guys or is it a bug?

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer : with the ConstraintLayout 2.0.0 alpha-5 you can simply use

> app:touchRegionId

in your "OnSwipe" for the same behaviour.  Also can use 'app:targetId' for "OnClick" usages.

Thanks @RuslanLeshchenko

---

Original answer :

I managed to do this finally by extending MotionLayout and override onTouchEvent to forward the event to required view.

Create the custom layout by extending MotionLayout

```
class SingleViewTouchableMotionLayout(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null) : MotionLayout(context, attributeSet) {

private var viewToDetectTouch1 :View? = null
private var viewToDetectTouchRes :Int = -1

private val viewRect = Rect()
private var touchStarted = false

init {

    setTransitionListener(object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
        override fun onTransitionTrigger(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean, p3: Float) {

        }

        override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTransitionChange(p0: MotionLayout, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Float) {
        }

        override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout, p1: Int) {
            touchStarted = false
        }
    })

    context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attributeSet,
            R.styleable.SingleViewTouchableMotionLayout,
            0, 0).apply {

        try {
            viewToDetectTouchRes = getResourceId(
                    R.styleable.SingleViewTouchableMotionLayout_viewToDetectTouch, 0)
        } finally {
            recycle()
        }
    }

}

override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow()
    viewToDetectTouch1 =  (parent as View).findViewById<View>(viewToDetectTouchRes)
}

override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    when (event.actionMasked) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
            touchStarted = false
            return super.onTouchEvent(event)
        }
    }
    if (!touchStarted) {
        viewToDetectTouch1?.getHitRect(viewRect)
        touchStarted = viewRect.contains(event.x.toInt(), event.y.toInt())
    }
    return touchStarted && super.onTouchEvent(event)
}
```

}

And add the custom attribute which will be used to declare the View that gonna receives the events to trigger the Transition/animation. 
Add these styleable to your attrs.xml in your res folder (res/values/attrs.xml)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="SingleViewTouchableMotionLayout">
        <attr name="viewToDetectTouch" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Thats it!!
This way we can archive MotionLayout OnSwipe on a specified view.

Layout XML file now will look like this :

```html
 <your_package.SingleViewTouchableMotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_file"

    app:viewToDetectTouch="@+id/triggerView"

        >
    <!-- Notice that 'app:viewToDetectTouch' hold the id of the  view we interested -->


    <!-- View we interested  -->
    <View

        android:id="@+id/triggerView"

        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        />

    </your_package.SingleViewTouchableMotionLayout>
```